# Hooking/Detour Virtual Functions

Tags: windows, hook, virtual-functions

I've been trying to properly hook/detour a virtual function in a class object, and I've had success in terms of having a different function called, but I must be doing something that's incorrect in terms of how the `this` keyword is passed to the function.

I read an article about hooking D3D functions in a similar fashion, and it mentioned that the compiler will turn a function such as `int Class::method(int)` into `int method(Class* this, int)`, but if I replace the address in the vtable with a function that is defined as such, the address for 'this' is incorrect, so that's probably not right.

How are member functions laid out by the compiler, and is it possible to represent it in non-member-function form so that I can set the address in the vtable to such a function and be able to refer to the appropriate object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your function as [thiscall](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8tkfbw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx&ei=pmNsTtLxBZPZiAK6x8nNDg&usg=AFQjCNH-BxObTRBfeQcn0UmJQzIC6GMSQg). It passes `this` on the `ecx` register. The way you've done it, the function was expecting `this` on the stack and reading the wrong value which probably belonged to another argument.

Comment: I tried to do that earlier, but the compiler told me I wasn't allowed to specify non-static non-member functions with thiscall. When I specified a function as I mentioned, I didn't actually use the `this` keyword as the argument name. Would specifying.a local variable and setting its value from the `ecx` register through raw assembly work? I think I'll look at how the assembly for something like `Class* obj = this` in an actual member function looks and then try to replicate it.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work as I expected, since functions without the `thiscall` convention clear out the `ecx` register at the beginning. I guess I'll have to define another class and use its function in the vtable instead in order to preserve the `thiscall`, unless there's a better way.

Comment: If that doesn't work, you could try creating a dummy class and later casting. Another option is putting in all the assembly code, like you said. You can do that with a [naked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ekezyy2(v=VS.71).aspx) function.

Comment: I ended up doing the dummy class suggestion and instantiating an instance so I could get the address of the functions through its vtable (and it worked fine), but the naked function sounds like a good idea because it avoids that unnecessary step and allows me to get exactly what I need. Thanks.